# Can you use ng-if/ng-show on icon element?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to have ng-show or ng-hide work on Ionic icon elements?

```
<i ng-show="seat1" id="space-1" class="ion-record"></i>
<i ng-show="seat2" id="space-2" class="ion-record"></i>
<i ng-show="seat3" id="space-3" class="ion-record"></i>
<i ng-show="seat4" id="space-4" class="ion-record"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Alternatively, you could wrap the icons in divs, too.

```
<div ng-show="seat1"><i id="space-1" class="ion-record"></i></div>
<div ng-show="seat2"><i id="space-2" class="ion-record"></i></div>
<div ng-show="seat3"><i id="space-3" class="ion-record"></i></div>
<div ng-show="seat4"><i id="space-4" class="ion-record"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ng-show or ng-if on every elements.
ng-if actually removes or recreate an DOM element, while ng-show only makes DOM element hidden or not. In this case if for example `seat1` is falsy, the  element will have class="ion-record ng-hide" and this ng-hide class makes your item

```
{display: none !important;}
```